# VB.NET Let message box linger after application quit

Tags: vb.net, locking

At a client of mine, in-house applications are all located on a network share. Users create shortcuts to the required applications from the network share so we can easily make sure everyone uses the latest version.

This works fairly well, although we often have an issue when users are still using applications when we'd like to release a new version. For most applications, we'd forcibly remove all the file locks on the server and release the new version. Not a very elegant solution, especially since we need assistance from another department for this.

For newer applications, I've developed a cleaner solution, where the application intermittently checks if it's still the most recent release. If it isn't, it shows a message to the user, asking him to quit the application at first convenience, or within 3 minutes. After 3 minutes, the application quits itself and all is well. However, some users will immediately try to re-start the application. The application will then show a simple MessageBox telling the user this version is currently not supported. My problem is this: while this MessageBox is visible, my executable is still locked.

I'm looking for any of the following solutions:

- Releasing all locks on the current assembly files from within code
- Showing a message box that lingers after the current assembly has exited

Comment: No.  This is all just wrong.  Write a proper installer, have people run locally installed copies of the application, and have that application auto-update itself.  When you do things the wrong way you end up with problems.  Trying to hack your way around stubbornly doing things the wrong way is not a solution.  Just do it the right way.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question but a possible alternative. For our software we've written launchers. The laucher checks the versioning before launching the actual application. Updates are completed if required and only then is the actual application launched. Works well enough.

Comment: @J... I know this is the cleanest solution. However, I have no control over the way my client chooses to run these things.

Comment: @MartenJacobs Nonsense.  They're running things this way because you've failed to provide them with a sensible solution to their problem (namely, ensuring that everyone uses the current version of the software).  They've implemented a hacky user-level updating scheme because your software does not intrinsically provide this function itself.  If you build it correctly they will have no need of this nonsense.

Comment: @J... My client has about fifty applications running, from which I've only worked on a few. They decided on this approach long before I got involved in any development. I'm in no position to force them to change this. 
However, it seems that ClickOnce deployment, as proposed in the accepted answer, is a standard solution that exactly fulfills my needs.

Comment: @MartenJacobs I completely agree that ClickOnce is a perfect solution here and falls firmly in the camp of "the right way" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **exactly precisely** the problem that .NET ClickOnce deployment is meant to solve.  Users have a shortcut they can click, the latest version is downloaded on application start, and there are no server-side executables to be locked if a user leaves their process open.

[ClickOnce Deployment Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4(v=vs.90).aspx)

[HowTo:Publish a ClickOnce Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems I was trying to reinvent the wheel. I think I'll use the deployment strategy [Starting the application from the Web or a Network Share](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71baz9ah(v=vs.90).aspx#Anchor_2).